# MySQL C++ Connector : error adding symbols: File format not recognized

Tags: c++, mysql, arm, mysql-connector

I have a problem on my cross-compile with Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and my ARM under Debian 8 (BeagleBone Black).

All is working fine, the code compile, at least the linking of the objects. 
I have a message like :

```
Project/lib/libmysqlcppconn-static.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
1>  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have searched and it seems to be an architecture problem, most of the time. But I tried with a 32 bit version.

For information, I have compiled the same program in the same context, without the Connector/C++ lib, but with another library, static too, with the same extension (. a) too, and it worked fine.
I searched in MySQL Documentation, but nothing explicitly saying that ARM is not supported.

Anyone has information on this?

(PS: First post, and school english, hope it's not too bad !)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll have much luck compiling for Linux using Visual Studio; Microsoft tools use COFF object format and Linux uses ELF (and the libraries are totally different), so at the binary level they are really talking different languages even if you are compiling for the same CPU instruction set.